# If “Josh” was put on hold by the moderators and/or quit, why is he still active as user159691?

Tags: discussion

If “Josh” was put on hold by the moderators and/or quit, why is he still active as [user159691](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/159691/user159691)? (And its clearly "Josh" from his answers on ELL.)

Today he/she/they [commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418845/the-old-switcheroo-where-did-the-eroo-suffix-come-from?__=996439195#comment1001607_418845) on this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418845/the-old-switcheroo-where-did-the-eroo-suffix-come-from) (etymology of -eroo).

Comment: A user can decide to delete his profile if he likes, for any reason at all, and can create another if he likes, again for any reason at all. One user I’m aware of has created a profile, ran it up to 20k+, deleted it, came back a few months Lester, created another account, ran that one up to 20k+ again, deleted it again, and then a few months later went through the whole process a *third* time. No idea why, but it’s not my business. Note that Josh wasn’t suspended, he quit, so he can un-quit whenever he wants. He just can’t get his old 100K+ account back. That’s gone forever.

Comment: @DanBron Create. Delete. Repeat. I know the person(s).

Comment: @NVZ Do you? I thought this person preceded your tenure. I haven’t seen them around in a while, unless I don’t recognize them in their latest costume.

Comment: @DanBron You underestimate how long I have been here. (Psst. I didn't even _sign up_ for a looong time) ;)

Comment: @NVZ Come to think of it, I’ve never seen you and Batman in the same room at the same time either .... ;)

Comment: Nobody here will confirm or deny any relation between the two user profiles, even if they can. I, however, believe that no one really quits the site just like that. ELU is so addictive that some way or another the users will return. I don't know about Josh, though.

Comment: Really? I don't think those two users write the same way. And why would the long time user Josh ask meta questions that sound so much like a new user? I'm just saying it doesn't seem plausible to me. But since you pointed it out, if there's any sign of abuse, the mods will handle it. If no abuse, then there's nothing to handle.

Comment: @Mitch Although I don't know and I don't care who is who and what they share, I do see some Josh-y vibes on checking the user's ELL.

Comment: Josh's "tell" was the typos...

Comment: well, the answer "styles" are identical, including copy and pasting from other sites and adding little original thought @Cascabel

Comment: Plus @Cascabel both Josh and user159691 has misspelled, in a quite Italian way (forgetting that 'y' in English–but not Italian–can be a vowel), *psychological* as *psicological*.

Answer (score 15):

Deleting a profile and quitting Stack Exchange are two different things, because people can have multiple profiles.

The only Stack Exchange policy on multiple profiles that I know of is that they cannot be used to “cheat” – cross vote, for example, or avoid a suspension.

Multiple profiles are useful, not just for technical reasons (such as testing, or organizing one’s tag subscriptions), but for social reasons. Multiple profiles allow a user to project different identities. For example, a person might wish to safely ask about something with a stigma, or otherwise raise a question that might result in an injustice if it was known who asked it.

So it is nobody’s business whether `Josh` and `user159691` are the same person unless there is cheating involved, and nobody in a position to know will confirm or deny it.